# What is the difference between $=$ and $:=$?

Tags: notation

I've encountered several usages of $:=$, for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/692444/678074)

> $$\alpha_i := \begin{cases} x_i & i \leq n \\ A & n< i \leq 2^k
>  \end{cases}$$

and  [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3421369/678074)

> Since $f$ is not constant, there exist some $a,b \in A$, $a \neq b$
>   such that $f(a) \neq f(b)$. **Take $g$ to be $g(x):=b$ for every $x \in
>  A$. Now $(f \circ g) (a)=f(b)$.** Hence we have $(f \circ g) (a)=f(b)
>  \neq f(a)$, so $f \circ g \neq f$.

However, I don't understand the difference between $=$ and $:=$. Is there any? I checked [this](https://www.rapidtables.com/math/symbols/Basic_Math_Symbols.html) source, but it didn't help.

Comment: Typically used in the definition of functions you are using.

Comment: @AndrewChin So if I understand you correctly, there is no substantial difference between the two?

Comment: As far as I know, you are correct.

Comment: $:=$ stands for 'equal to by definition'.

Comment: @KaboMurphy The source I quoted within the post also said that $:=$ stood for "equal by definition", but unfortunately, I don't understand what makes it different from $=$.

Comment: You can use $:=$ when you are first introducing a new symbol to define what it is.  e.g., $f(x) := x^2$ means that we are defining $f(x)$ to be $x^2$, not deducing that $f(x) = x^2$ from other propositions. It is often used in blackboard talks because it is faster than writing a complete sentence definition.  It's generally only ever used once per object defined, and only when the symbol is first seen.

Comment: There's no functional difference, if that's what you're asking. But it can make texts easier to read since it makes it clearer that the equality is something that is taken to be true by definition, not something derived or deduced.